# Нужно сделать команду подсчета твоих рефералов бот тг python aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

могу я у тебя узнать строчки кода для бота, по реф системе я написал команду забиндил под кнопки в итоге у меня есть кнопка получить ссылку( бот выдаёт ссылку), мне осталась команда которая позволяет боту подсчитать количество приглашённых юзеров, поможешь?

[image: кнопка с ссылкой работает, с рефералами нет]

```
link = await get_start_link(str(message.from_user.username), encode=True)
  result: 'https://t.me/MyBot?start='
```

#после знака `=` будет закодированный никнейм юзера, который создал реф ссылку, вместо него можно вставить и его id

```
  # код получения ссылки если что
  await message.answer(f"Ваша реф. ссылка {link}")
```

Comment: Теперь вам надо поставить какую нибудь базу данных, научиться работать с ней из питон скрипта, записывать в нее пользователей. После сделать реакцию на вход новых пользователей по ссылкам, начать это писать в БД, указывая по чьему приглашению пришел чел. И вот тогда уже можно будет к кнопке просмотра рефералов вешать обработчик, который в БД посчитает количество и выведет. На текущий момент у вас готово процентов 5 от необходимого

Comment: У меня есть БД которая записывает юзеров в текстовый документ, можете подсказать скрипт для реакции на вход юзеров по ссылкам, и скрипт обработчика?

Comment: Слона надо есть по частям. Т.е. разбивать задачу на мелкие и каждую в отдельности решать. И начинать каждую, если не знаете как делать, стоит искать в гугле. Мне вот гугл например сходу дал такую https://habr.com/ru/post/561112/ статью. Правда до хранения в БД они не дошли

Comment: Я что то не вижу, что бы вы в ссылку добавили что то о пользователе. ник или id. добавьте его туда. потом научитесь выделять его обратно из ссылки, когда пользователь заходит. После этого переходите к записи в базу данных информации о пользователе и id того пользователя, который пригласил данного

Comment: @dp.message_handler(Command("start"), state=None)

async def welcome(message):
    joinedFile = open("user.txt","r")
    joinedUsers = set ()
    for line in joinedFile:
        joinedUsers.add(line.strip())

    if not str(message.chat.id) in joinedUsers:
        joinedFile = open("user.txt","a")
        joinedFile.write(str(message.chat.id)+ "\n")
        joinedUsers.add(message.chat.id)

    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"ПРИВЕТ, *{message.from_user.first_name},* БОТ РАБОТАЕТ", reply_markup=keyboard.start, parse_mode='Markdown') - мой код БД